# Remote Ubuntu Server crashed while configuring OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, openvpn

When I tried to follow these instructions my remote linux (ubuntu) server crashed. I don't have physical access to this computer.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN

I will try again with another remote linux server (ubuntu again). Can someone give any advice on how to not lose the SSH connection permanently while trying to setup the OpenVPN connection? Thanks.

Comment: Simple understand the routing implications before starting the daemon.  probably best to test things on a box you can touch or gave out of band access to .

Answer (score 1):

Practice makes perfect.
Like [Zoredache said](https://serverfault.com/questions/531430/remote-ubuntu-server-crashed-while-configuring-openvpn#comment608406_531430), keep trying until you can do the routing diagnosis in your head before throwing the switch. Preferably on a box you have physical (or IPMI, remote KVM, etc.) access to so that when (not if) you screw up you can fix the problem.

**Other free advice:**
Whenever you're doing something that can affect routing or firewall configuration, ***DON'T*** set it up so it takes effect across reboots, and set a watchdog.

Something as simple as `shutdown -r +5` before you pull the trigger will ensure that if you lock yourself out your system will reboot and be accessible again. And if everything works you can just cancel the shutdown.

(I've been doing this for a good long while. I'm pretty good at it and haven't broken things in recent memory. I *still* set a watchdog before I touch a firewall or VPN configuration.)